# Too much data in C# windows form combobox, taking 30 sec to show the windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I am creating a windows form, that contains a simple combo box, which has around 100000 items. After loading all those items when I try to show the form useing showDialog() method it is taking 30 sec to show the form.

Is there any way that I can show it immediately ?

Comment: Do you really think that it's practical for a user to scroll through 100,000 items in a `ComboBox`?  Do what any sensible developer does in such cases and use some system where the user starts typing and gets a filtered list of matching items that is much smaller than the full list.

Comment: First, no improvements can be made out of what you ask, since no sample code is provided. So provide some sample code for a start. Second, as stated by @jmcilhinney, I also don't think it is a good approach to display 100K items in a single `ComboBox`, it is not the proper control for the job. Third, `DataBinding` might be faster to fill the control rather than just iterating through a collection and adding items one by one. Or else, use a second thread to fill the `ComboBox` then add it to your form, or even perhaps the use of a `ProgressBar` might help depending on the actual objective.

Comment: So as you can see, there is no one simple answer to the matter. There can be a thousand ways to solve your problems depending on the what is needed. Provide your code sample, then perhaps one may see the flaws into it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @jmcilhinney, it is not practical to load all this data to a combobox. Your system could (and it is) getting unresponsive on other situations.

There might be a lot of reasons for you have to do this, and since you are not disclosing everything, I can give a suggestion to answer your question - remember, not the good way, but would make things better for a while.

You might be binding your information on your load process. Separate it, make it async.
There are several ways of doing this, like making an async call to a internal method and set your `ComboBox.DataSource` or `ComboBox.DataBind`.

Also, on the end of your load/initialization of your window, set the cursor do hourglass/wait. Then set it back to the original one (might be the normal pointer). This would give the effect that the dialog is shown but it is yet loading. It is a lot better for the user showing that you are loading info.

But after that, try filtering data as you type, as suggested by @jmcilhinney. Even if it a fixed list, make it editable and filter data. Don't let the user see more than +1000. You should find a way to show the user that has too much thing and provide means to make your data filterable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data loading code for combobox in the load event, which I think you do. Move that code to a separate function and call that from a timer or thread. Or you can make the function async and then call that function from load event. This will not keep your form waiting till all the data is loaded in the combobox.